# Evaluating Toeplitz determinant

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How can one evaluate $-\text{log}~ \text{Det}(I_{i-j}(x))$ where $x>200$ and $I_{\nu}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind and $i,j = 1 \cdots 100$ and the determinant is take of the matix whose elements are given by $A_{ij} =  I_{i-j}(x)$. I used Scipy/Python and it gives me an incorrect answer. I want to see how much better Mathematica does. Note that  $I_{i-j}(200)$ is a huge number for any $i-j$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I get with Mathematica:

```
logdet[x_, prec_] := - Log @ Det @ N[Array[BesselI[#1-#2, x]&, {100, 100}], prec]
```

Presumably due to subtractive cancellation, a high precision is needed to get an accurate result, so:

```
r500 = logdet[200, 500]
```

> -9033.801557200126884639983232381821638986208454697027595029420498495859730519\
>   029590617989373466937836223259754375229723311300136058858941346024154635908053\
>   762729182813641676207541530844596440371730202099559364747933131151396757544867\
>   410989540289820352083687426358192116464335718811026707179015898854249615451052\
>   308452992411926795485314268493234726335846547885562794131295349448973511839300\
>   690475561361508703872728426715140348231043410320195012668497801821524162092336\
>   9400443012392291448771312756532037106

Comparing this to a computation with a bit more precision:

```
r510 = logdet[200, 510]
```

> -9033.801557200126884639983232381821638986208454697027595029420498495859730519\
>   029590617989373466937836223259754375229723311300136058858941346024154635908053\
>   762729182813641676207541530844596440371730202099559364747933131151396757544867\
>   410989540289820352083687426358192116464335718811026707179015898854249615451052\
>   308452992411926795485314268493234726335846547885562794131295349448973511839300\
>   690475561361508703881209596637699666119599037581235795792730971525348781541540\
>   179968386785031399656551557996358738271830794709

The difference is:

```
Log10[r500 - r510]
```

> -404.0715442354949104419778748391483390025461143878688319727113963282042725909\
>   57302327785726278047318

So, I would expect r500 to have an accuracy of about 404:

```
SetAccuracy[r500, 404]
```

> -9033.801557200126884639983232381821638986208454697027595029420498495859730519\
>   029590617989373466937836223259754375229723311300136058858941346024154635908053\
>   762729182813641676207541530844596440371730202099559364747933131151396757544867\
>   410989540289820352083687426358192116464335718811026707179015898854249615451052\
>   308452992411926795485314268493234726335846547885562794131295349448973511839300\
>   6904755613615087039

Comment: Very informative answer. And the precision becomes even more important for x >> 200. Thanks. I wonder why Python can't handle this but that's not something for here.